# Seeking official topographic maps of Cuba?

Tags: data

Any ideas as to where I might find official topo maps of Cuba at scales of !:50K or larger?  NGIA won't release the ones they have, and similarly they can't be purchased in Cuba.

Answer (score 1):

From the look of the [Data Portal](http://dataportals.org/) site it looks like that the Cuban government have not published new maps.
You can look into old Cuban maps in [Old Maps online](http://www.oldmapsonline.org/map/cuni/1176375) and look at free maps of Cuba. For an example look at this map [image]. 
Some of this map are quite old, but maybe this can help you.

Comment: If this is helpful please mark this answer  as  answered.

Comment: New maps  have certainly  been published; they're just very difficult to obtain!